# ¿Cómo podría obviar documentos duplicados en mongodb?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Supongamos que tengo un documento con la siguiente estructura:

```
{
  {
    id: "60s4545454454444477c1",
      status: "true"
    users: [
      {
        id: "54s4545454454444477b4",
        status: true,
        name: "carlos"
        lastName: "palazolo"
      },
      {
        id: "54s4545454454444477b5",
        status: true,
        name: "Maria"
        lastName: "Rodriguez"
      },
    ]  
  }
},
  {
    id: "60s4545454454444477c2",
      status: "true"
    users: [
      {
        id: "54s4545454454444477b4",
        status: true,
        name: "carlos"
        lastName: "palazolo"
      },
      {
        id: "54s4545454454444477b9",
        status: true,
        name: "Ana"
        lastName: "Rivero"
      },
    ]  
  }
```

Si quisiera obtener todos los usuarios con `status = true`, pero si hay duplicados solo quiero obtener uno de ellos, ¿cómo podría hacer?

En el ejemplo, los usuarios activos son *carlos*, *maria* y *ana*, pero *carlos* está dos veces, (aparece en 2 documentos distintos): en ese caso solo me interesa uno; la respuesta a la consulta sería algo así:

```
{
  id: "54s4545454454444477b4",
  status: true,
  name: "carlos"
  lastName: "palazolo"
},
{
  id: "54s4545454454444477b5",
  status: true,
  name: "Maria"
  lastName: "Rodriguez"
},

{
  id: "54s4545454454444477b9",
  status: true,
  name: "Ana"
  lastName: "Rivero"
}
```

Comment: Por si te sirve de ayuda https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: ese operador lo revisé pero no se si es que no se aplicarlo a la forma en como tengo el documento o es que no sirve para este caso.

Comment: Sería mas fácil ayudarte si pudieras [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que has hecho para obtener los datos. Desde ahí podemos proponerte cambios para llegar al resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Haber prueba este código.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {"users.status": true} // filtramos
    },
    {
        "$project": { "users": 1, "_id": 0 }  // mostramos solo algunos campos
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$users"  // separamos el arreglo por documentos
    },
    {
        "$group": {                            // empezamos con la unión
            "_id": "nuevo_id",                 // creamos un nuevo "_id" -> es necesario
            "users": {"$addToSet": "$users"}   // unimos los documentos en un arreglo sin documentos repetidos
        }
    }
])
```

Creo que ayuda a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Voy a probarlo amigo, pero una duda... en que parte de esa query se evita insertar 2 veces el documento repetido ( Carlos Palazolo ) ?

Comment: Justo al crear el atributo **users** cuando usa `$addToSet`.

Comment: Sería bueno que explicaras lo que hace el código. Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad. Puedes leer [answer]. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras buenas tardes, creo que en el código mismo lo explico que hace cada etapa del proceso, la respuesta está en código `bson` y el resultado es como se solicita en la pregunta. No he respondido en `Phyton` por que no conozco mucho sobre el lenguaje, pero a través de esta respuesta se puede acoplar a cualquier lenguaje de programación. Ahora si respondí en codigo  `bson` es porque en la pregunta pone la etiqueta de `mongodb` y de alguna manera quise ayudar a resolver este problema.